How to get list managed correctly in Kotlin?
I have a list of items like
val myList = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
and need to take first three elements, which I do like this:
myList.take(3).forEach { }
and want to get the rest of elements by doing something like this:
myList.restElements.forEach { }
where the extension/function restElements lists all elements 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 by jumping over the first three ones.
Is there any short feature in Kotlin for that?

I'm not sure I understand correctly. Are you just looking for list.drop(3).forEach { ... }?

Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I didn't find it. Thank you. @Utsav has already given an answer below, too.

Note that myList.drop(3) will create a copy of the list, so be aware of that if you have a very large list and very limited memory available. In such a case, consider using myList.subList(3, myList.size) instead. The latter returns a view of the original list without copying it.

@k314159 thank you. Does the myList.take(3) also make a copy? I assume, it does, doesn't it?

@MarkDelphi yes it does. Just like Leviathan says in his answer.

Utsav katharotiya's answer is perfectly fine, I just want to point out that both take and drop each create a new list where elements from myList are copied into. The elements themselves are not duplicated, just their references, but you still have two additional lists with their own backing structure.
I say this because there is an alternative where only a view on myList is created:
val firstThree = myList.subList(0, 3) // [1, 2, 3]
val restElements = myList.subList(3, myList.size) // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

This will use myList as its backing list, so no elements are copied: Only the start and end indices are modified so it looks like they are separate lists.
Because this still uses the same myList under the hood there are three major behavioral differences to the take/drop approach:

It's faster because no new lists are created and no elements must be copied. It also uses less memory. Don't put too much emphasis on this, though: Unless you have huge lists (with millions of entries) this usually won't have any noticeable impact.
If you change myList to be a MutableList any non-structural modifications(*) to the list will also be directly visible in the sub lists. This also works the other way round: Non-structural modifications of firstThree or restElements are also directly visible in myList.
As already mentioned in the comments, be aware that subList's behavior is undefined when you specify indices that are not present in the list. You'll most likely end up with an IndexOutOfBoundsException, the actual behavior depends on the List implementation.

This may or may not be what you want, you should be aware though that there are alternatives with different semantics so you can make a conscious decision what to choose.
As a closing note: As seen above, subList is much more fragile than take or drop. Also the API surface is not as concise: You can easily mess things up with an Off-by-one error. You might well decide that the minor performance and memory impact from take/drop is preferable to the more verbose subList for the sake of readability by more clearly stating the intent.

(*): A non-structural modifications would be the set method which leaves the list the same while only replacing an element. This is in contrast to structural modifications like add and remove which results in undefined behavior and may throw a ConcurrentModificationException when the sublists are accessed afterwards.

Good points. In fact, the person writing the code that uses subList as above might not even realise that myList is actually a MutableList. It may be declared as a List (which only means it's unmodifiable by the code that declares it) but it might actually be mutated by another part of the program while you're traversing the sublists. If that is a possibility stick to take and drop.

Great answer! Something to keep in mind: unlike take(3), sublist(0, 3) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the list has fewer than 3 elements.
